# Is it okay to update accepted answer on my own question?

Tags: discussion, editing

Yesterday I asked this question – [All requests go into ELB surge queue](https://serverfault.com/questions/871286/all-requests-go-into-elb-surge-queue), and eventually got a partial reply which lead me a right direction of finding a more clear answer, that was provided by the person who replied to my own question.

I didn't want to post another answer, as it would be almost the same as the one already posted, so I edited existing answer, providing additional details of my findings, plus results of tests I did, and marked it as accepted.

As I don't have enough reputation on serverfault, to make an edit, it was a suggested edit([you can check it here](https://serverfault.com/review/suggested-edits/338578)), and it was rejected with a reason:

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no
>   sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an
>   answer.

I cannot see how my edit could have been just a comment, as it's quiet big.
So the question is: should i have posted my  edit as a different answer even though, it just expansion of already existing answer?

A person, whose answer I edited, did approved my suggested edit even so it was rejected by peer review. So I'm not trying to get my edits to get approved, I just want to learn the best way to resolve this next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, yes editing is encouraged!

When you edit a question or an answer (and you don't have [>2k reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/edit) yet) it is entered in a review queue for peer review.

Edits remain in a pending state until they get enough votes to either approve them and make the edits take effect or reject them and discard the edit. **Two votes** in either direction will finalize the action, except on Stack Overflow where three votes are required.

The original author of the question or answer that is edited also gets notified and (if they act faster than the review queue) they can accept the edit as well, negating the requirement for two or three votes in the review queue.

https://serverfault.com/help/editing and https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/edit

---

Your proposed edit was reviewed and rejected by **one reviewer** with the default rejection: *"This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.*"

After that **it remained in the review queue** pending either one more rejection vote or two accept votes.

Subsequently the edit was **accepted by the author** of the original answer and applied.

Answer (score 3):

Edits should strive to be "seamless", and when done right, the entire answer should continue to read as though it was the work of a single author.  It was the jarring "key change" (as it were), between the original answer and your edit, that triggered the "attempt to reply" reflex (honestly, I think I probably would have reviewed that edit the same way duenni did).  The fact your edit was much longer than the original might not have helped, either.

To help the process along next time, I'd suggest making your edit more "streamlined" with the rest of the post you're augmenting.  Skip the "update from OP" and separator, and just go straight into your expansion.

Imagine you'd written the first two paragraphs (the original answer) yourself, what would you put next?  I probably would have started with the docs link and quote, moved on to the implications, and then closed out with the real-world testing you conducted.

Finally, welcome to Server Fault, and good on you for doing the work to keep things tidy.

Comment: `I'd suggest making your edit more "streamlined" with the rest of the post you're augmenting` – this is right to the point. Will keep it in mind from now on